# How to store IP address that accesses a specific url into a file

Tags: php, wordpress, security, joomla, ddos

I'm no coder and I'm running into an issue. What I would like to do is to store into a file all the IPs that try accessing specific URLS so that I can build a list of IPs of people that are either trying to see if my site is made with a specific CMS or try to hack their way into it.

I know I can access such data in the server log files but automating the task would save me a lot of time in the long run.

Is there so code that I could add on the specific URLs that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$pathToLogFile="";
file_put_contents($pathToLogFile, "\nIP Address". $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],FILE_APPEND)
?>
```

Remember to provide an absolute path if you're placing this file in multiple directories, and make sure you initialize a blank file at that path

Comment: I'm file_get_contents'ing before, and appending the ip log afterwards

Comment: I would suggest just using FILE_APPEND rather than reading the entire file in every time, though.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, you made my day, I'll try this out very soon. I do not doubt it will do exactly what I need. Now I should be able to get data from the specific log file and return the unwanted traffic back from were it originates, saving myself server ressources and increasing load on the spam servers. And Merry Christmas to all of this great community.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Wow I never realized that flag existe. Ya learn something new every day.